# EDT and EST timestamp sqlldr data load in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, timezone, sql-loader

I have issue while loading data from flat file to Oracle database with Timestamp column via sqlloader.
The problem is I have a data for both EST and EDT like below mentioned format

**test_data.dat**

```
Thu Mar 07 14:27:14 EST 2013
Thu Mar 07 14:27:27 EST 2013
Tue Apr 09 18:20:54 EDT 2013
Tue Apr 09 18:24:26 EDT 2013
```

**My sqldrfile.ctl** code is below

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'test_data.dat'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE MY_TABLE    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
        "DOC_DATE_ADDED" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY",
)
```

**Rejected_data.bad** the below two records not recognized and went to bad file

```
Tue Apr 09 18:20:54 EDT 2013
Tue Apr 09 18:24:26 EDT 2013
```

Other two EST records loaded correctly into oracle table.. I need a sqlldr code to load for both the timestamp EST and EDT. Please guide me on this.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change the format of the data in the file, and can't manipulate the file before loading it, you could replace a specific EDT value with the region value `US/Eastern` (or any suitable value like `America/New_York`) with [an SQL operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1226):

```
"DOC_DATE_ADDED" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY"
  "REPLACE(:DOC_DATE_ADDED, 'EDT', 'US/Eastern')"
```

(split into two lines for readability, but you can do that in the control file too).

When your sample data file is loaded the table contains:

```
select to_char(doc_date_added, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZD') as TZD,
   to_char(doc_date_added, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') as TZR
from my_table;

TZD                     TZR                          
----------------------- ------------------------------
2013-03-07 14:27:14 EST 2013-03-07 14:27:14 EST        
2013-03-07 14:27:27 EST 2013-03-07 14:27:27 EST        
2013-04-09 18:20:54 EDT 2013-04-09 18:20:54 US/EASTERN 
2013-04-09 18:24:26 EDT 2013-04-09 18:24:26 US/EASTERN
```

... so you preserve the EST/EDT split; though the `TZR` shows `US/EASTERN` and `EST` - so it might be better to change the `EST` value as well, with a nested `REPLACE` or with:

```
"DOC_DATE_ADDED" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY"
  "REGEXP_REPLACE(:DOC_DATE_ADDED, 'E[SD]T', 'US/Eastern')"
```

Or if all your values are always EST/EDT, you could do the timestamp conversion explicitly and just cut out the actual string you're given:

```
"DOC_DATE_ADDED" CHAR "FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(:DOC_DATE_ADDED, 1, 19)
  || SUBSTR(:DOC_DATE_ADDED, 25, 29), 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY'), 'US/Eastern')"
```

Which loads your data as:

```
TZD                     TZR                          
----------------------- ------------------------------
2013-03-07 14:27:14 EST 2013-03-07 14:27:14 US/EASTERN 
2013-03-07 14:27:27 EST 2013-03-07 14:27:27 US/EASTERN 
2013-04-09 18:20:54 EDT 2013-04-09 18:20:54 US/EASTERN 
2013-04-09 18:24:26 EDT 2013-04-09 18:24:26 US/EASTERN
```

The danger with that is that if you ever do get a value in a different time zone it'll silently be recorded against the wrong region, whereas the first version will either process it successfully or reject it, depending on whether it's recognised (i.e. in Wernfried's first list).

Answer (score 3):

`EDT` ist not a valid timezone **region**, this is a time zone abbreviation.

Valid regions are these ones:

```
SELECT * 
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
WHERE TZNAME = TZABBREV;

TZNAME  TZABBREV
======================
CET     CET
CST     CST
EET     EET
EST     EST
GMT     GMT
HST     HST
MET     MET
MST     MST
PST     PST
WET     WET
```

The reason for that you see by this query. `EDT` may represent several different time zone regions from UTC-04:00 to UTC-06:00.

```
SELECT TZNAME, TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
WHERE TZABBREV = 'EDT'
ORDER BY 2;

TZNAME                          TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)
------------------------------- -----------------
America/Santo_Domingo                    -04:00           
America/Fort_Wayne                       -05:00           
America/Grand_Turk                       -05:00           
America/Indiana/Indianapolis             -05:00           
America/Indiana/Marengo                  -05:00           
America/Indiana/Petersburg               -05:00           
US/Michigan                              -05:00           
America/Detroit                          -05:00           
US/Eastern                               -05:00           
America/Indiana/Vevay                    -05:00           
America/Indiana/Vincennes                -05:00           
America/Indiana/Winamac                  -05:00           
America/Indianapolis                     -05:00           
America/Iqaluit                          -05:00           
America/Jamaica                          -05:00           
America/Kentucky/Louisville              -05:00           
America/Kentucky/Monticello              -05:00           
America/Louisville                       -05:00           
America/Montreal                         -05:00           
America/Nassau                           -05:00           
America/New_York                         -05:00           
America/Nipigon                          -05:00           
America/Pangnirtung                      -05:00           
America/Port-au-Prince                   -05:00           
America/Thunder_Bay                      -05:00           
America/Toronto                          -05:00           
Canada/Eastern                           -05:00           
EST5EDT                                  -05:00           
Jamaica                                  -05:00           
US/East-Indiana                          -05:00           
America/Cancun                           -06:00           
America/Indiana/Tell_City                -06:00           

32 rows selected.
```

I assume you have to modify your text file. I don't know if sqlloader supports any in-line transaltions, e.g. from `EST` to `EST5EDT`

Answer (score 0):

For those developers from other countries, I would like to quote [askanydifference website](https://askanydifference.com/) here:

> The key difference between Eastern Standard Time and Eastern Daylight
> Time lies in the fact that although they are used for the same time
> zones, they are used at different times of the year.
>
> The Eastern Standard Time is used during the fall-winter season. It is
> used from the first Sunday of November.
>
> Eastern Daylight Time is also an hour ahead of the Eastern Standard
> Time.

The basic understanding of EDT and EST goes a long way in dealing with times during development in any kind of programming language.